# Font too sharp in MonoGame

Tags: c#, import, fonts, monogame, antialiasing

I have a problem in *Monogame* where I have the following font:
[image: Font]

However, when I render it in Monogame it appears like this:
[image]

Where has there a way to fix this anti-anti-aliasing problem without re-importing the font at multiple different sizes?

P.S. The font I am rendering was imported at **100px** and scaled down to around **20px**. I do this to prevent re-importing multiple fonts at different sizes.

Comment: _” The font I am rendering was imported at 100px and scaled down to around 20. I do this to prevent re-importing multiple fonts at different sizes”_ - there is your problem right there.  Why did you do that?  Fonts are trivial in XNA and are already prepared for you.  Be sure to only use the fonts you are legally allowed to use by the framework

Comment: _"Be sure to only use the fonts you are legally allowed to use by the framework"_ I'm sorry for my misunderstanding, but what specifies as an "illegal font"?

Comment: But I've seen people used many different fonts, especially using Monogame, when looking for a solution. Sadly, there isn't any way to tell if the font is a "rasterized" font, and surely most fonts out today would have that requirement.

Comment: I know I'm not, I checked the license distributed by the creator of the font. Also, this is not helping solve the question. The question is about anti-aliasing, not license rights. As well as that, XNA is discontinued, which is replaced by Monogame, which they would surely be violating something from creating the framework its self.

Comment: ah yep, sorry, but is there not a way to use a shader or something like that to create alti-aliasing on the font?

Comment: Yes, that's where sampling schems like bilinear or trilinear come into play though you scale things all the time at runtime when you don't need to might save texture memory but it does impact performance.  The issue you have looks to be a sampling issue (hence my first comment).  It's been ages since I've done XNA, you might have to do your own font renderer together with your shader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures, I accidentally kept instancing hundreds of text objects in the update function by accident instead of in the Start function. Just instancing one fixed everything!